# Sending GET data via fetch() in body instead of specifying it in the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I am trying to convert this jQuery call to native Javascript using fetch() as mentioned in MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options).

```
        $.ajax(
        {
            method: "GET",
            url: CB_ABS_URI + "ajax/get-checkin.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { DwellingUnitID:DwellingUnitID },
        })
```

to

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

        postData(CB_ABS_URI + "ajax/get-checkin.php", { DwellingUnitID: DwellingUnitID })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
          });
```

But I can't seem to send GET data in the body. Is adding the query to ajax/get-checkin.php the only way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I can't seem to send GET data in the body

`fetch` makes a clear distinction between the query string in the URL and the data in the request body (unlike jQuery which switches between them depending on the request method).

> Is adding the query to ajax/get-checkin.php the only way ?

Yes, see [the documentation](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api):

> If you want to work with URL query parameters:
>
> ```
> var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api"),
>     params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431}
> Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
> fetch(url).then(/* … */)
> ```